# Getting Permission denied when executing commands using Process Builder

Tags: java, jhipster, processbuilder

I am trying to run the `/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.1.0/bin/jhipster` command to generate jhipster application using java.

And I am getting the error

```
bash: /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.1.0/bin/jhipster: Permission denied
```

Can you explain why I get this error?

Comment: Presumably you don't have execute rights on the file. If you `ls -l` it should show a `x` somewhere in the first column.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline the file have the following permission.
**lrwxrwxrwx**

Comment: That'll be a link. The file linked to will also need execute permissions.

Comment: The linked file also have the same permissions.